# kernel mem parameter

Tags: kernel, memory

As a last resort to my [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82917/ubuntu-detects-only-3-2gb-ram-on-a-64bit-os), I am yet to try the `mem` parameter of kernel to force it to use the specified amount of RAM. Short Summary - I can only see 3.2GB RAM on a 64bit OS and am not sure ifs a hardware limitation, so wants to try as I found a post on [Ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1031595).

My question is if its ok to play with my resident Ubuntu install or should I be using a live bootable usb? What values do I try (I have 6GB with only 3.2GB being usable) and how to keep it safe? I don't want to burn any of my hardware component at this point of time or make the system unbootable.

Running Ubuntu `11.10` with kernel `3.0.0-13-generic`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weird, that Ubuntuforums link wants a login but I can view random other threads without logging in.

Anyway I'm guessing you're referring to `mem=xM` in your bootloader. This is perfectly safe to try on your current install. For 6GB you want `mem=6144M` (6*1024).

Just try tacking it onto the end of the line with the other options, which will include such things as `quiet` `splash` `ro` `root=UUID=$stuff`.

For safety, I would not recommend you edit any config files to do this the first time. While booting, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to get into GRUB and then press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the highlighted grub entry. You can move around with the cursor keys to find the line you want to edit; add `mem=6144M` onto the end and boot (see directions at the bottom of the screen).

If it works, add it to `/etc/default/grub` in the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, and run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: This only seems to be capping the RAM to use and not a way to force the kernel to use more RAM if it already isn't. I tried `mem=3500M` since I only have 4GB plugged in right now and it doesn't work. It do works if I cap it lower at 2GB `mem=2048M`. But your answer explains the question, so I will mark it as answer. Thanks!

Comment: Since you are probably on a x86 system (32 or 64 bit, does not matter), the `mem` parameter works slightly different from what @Caesium explained: "mem=nn[KMG] […] [X86] Work as limiting max address." ([see](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt)). I had to use `mem=6700M` to lower `free -m` available memory from 5763 MiB to 5365 MiB. Found out by experimenting, since I did not know the size and location of reserved address space.