# Installation only recognizes 3 GB of memory after RAM upgrade

Tags: upgrade, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Ubuntu only show 3GB of RAM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32272/why-does-ubuntu-only-show-3gb-of-ram)

I recently upgraded my system from 2 to 4 GB of memory. When I booted into Ubuntu, it's only recognizing 3 GB.

I followed some instructions on adding the PAE; now when I boot up my kernel has switched from generic to PAE but I'm still only showing 3 GB. How do I get it to read all 4 GB?

I went to the Software Center and found the PAE, then when I clicked "More info" it shows a few more packages with it but they aren't checked. Should I check them to be added also? Will this make Ubuntu recognize my 4 GB?

Comment: Is this relevant at all? http://askubuntu.com/questions/20571/why-is-more-than-3gb-of-ram-not-recognised-when-using-amd64

Comment: Does `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep pae` (in a Terminal) produce any output? If it doesn't print out any output then your CPU is not pae-capable and is therefore not able to address more than 3GB of RAM.

Comment: Can you please post screenshot of disk utility?

Comment: @robert The red color is just there to highlight the search term you supplied to `grep`. The fact that `pae` is listed at all, in any color, means that your CPU does support it.

Comment: Does your motherboard have on board video? When you don't have a separate video card, some of your main memory is allocated for video. The amount is controlled in the BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, what version of Ubuntu have you installed? 32bits or 64bits?
If I'm correct 32bits systems won't be able to use more than 3Gb of memory, try with the 64bits version.

Comment: That's why people are suggesting to use the PAE kernel; this allows using more than 3 GB on 32-bit.

Comment: But then why not use the 64bits directly?

Comment: PAE is useful on systems that can't handle the 64-bit version of Ubuntu (i.e. no x86_64 support). Also, 64-bit-compiled binaries are larger and a 64-bit system will "use" more memory. Using the PAE kernel is a good way to take advantage of extra memory while sparing the user having to reinstall the whole system. Nevertheless, the assertion that 32-bit systems won't be able to use more than 3GB is incorrect.

Comment: As I had commented earlier on here I bought a new computer and installed the 64 bit.I had been running the 32 bit and added the pae but still no luck.my new system has ubuntu as only OS and 64 bit.

Comment: Oh yeah the 64 bit recognizes all 8 gigs

Answer (score 0):

You said

> lshw -short -C memory and it seems that **ubuntu is showing that I can
>   have a maximum of 4 gigs** but still only reading 3 gigs.

Why do you say it is only *reading* 3 gigs? What do you mean by "reading"? What command are you using that shows it is "only reading 3 gigs?" My guess is that your system is recognizing all 4 GB.

The easiest command you can use to confirm this is:

```
top
```

Here is what mine shows on a 4GB system with 64 bit Ubuntu:

> Mem:   3930080k total,

Here is another well-used command:

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo
```

Mine shows:

> MemTotal:        3930080 kB

You can also try:

```
dmesg|grep Memory
```

Or, if you install the hwinfo package, run it:

```
hwinfo
```

Finally, if you really don't see around 4GB from those commands, and the difference is not due to an onboard video card, here is a similar question:
[Ubuntu detects only 3.2GB RAM on a 64bit OS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82917/ubuntu-detects-only-3-2gb-ram-on-a-64bit-os#question)

Comment: @MountainX-I say reading basically because through every command you just posted I got 3 gigs read by ubuntu.My bios detected all 4 gigs.As I stated here I added the 64bit pae to my 32 bit version of ubuntu 11.10.I couldnt figure it out but no worried I sold that computer and bought a new.I installed ubuntu 64bit as my only os and it reads all 8 gigs

Comment: also,I was running an ati x1050 card pci standalone but my new computer doesnt even have onboard

Comment: ok, enjoy your new computer!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your motherboard does not support more than 3GB of RAM. Which board do you have?

This article has some pretty good info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_GB_barrier

Comment: -the mobo supports 4 gigs as in the bios the 4 gigs is recognized