# Installed Ubuntu via Wubi, only reading 2.9 GiB of Ram

Tags: 10.10, wubi, memory, ram

So I just installed Ubuntu 10.10 via Wubi over Win XP Pro 32bit, my processor is X64, and I have 4GB of RAM installed, the Ubuntu installs as 64bit but it only shows 2.9 GiB of RAM even tho the OS is 64bit, why is this? The whole reason i did this was because with windows xp you cannot use a 32bit license for 64bit version, unlike Vista/7 which works as long as version is same (pro ultim etc) and I need 64bit, but its only reading 2.9 :S?

My OS is `Linux ubuntu 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 14:56:25 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Comment: Does windows show all your ram ?

Comment: windows is 32bit, it shows 3 gigs of the 4 because being 32bit..but  why is 64bit ubuntu showing 2.9?

Comment: Are you sure you installed the 64bit version?  What does `uname -a` say?

Comment: What BIOS (and which version) do you have? Sometimes there are problems with older versions: http://askubuntu.com/a/83608/236

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, which is why it has been closed. If you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.